# Scaffolding support in Sharp Architecture 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding, sharp-architecture

have they dropped support for scaffolding in SA 2.0. i have downloaded the [templify-project](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture). I installed templify and created a solution but the project structure it created did not include `tools` and `tools/CrudScaffolding` that are supposed to contain code generation templates.
So question is: have they dropped code generation capabilities with SA 2.0 and additionally if some one could point me to a demo with SA 2.0 i will be indeed grateful

Comment: the latest version of sharp architecture is `1.9.somehting` that uses MVC3 the, `2.0` of SA version uses the MVC (probably 2)...